# How can I test if code has debuggers?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, rspec

I am working with a team and we are constantly putting `console.log` and `debugger` or `binding.pry` (Ruby) into our code. What is the appropriate strategy for going about to write a unit test for this? We currently do not have unit testing (I know, it's ridiculous) but this is something we need to handle, because we are accidentally pushing `console.log` and `binding.pry` into production.

Comment: binding.pry will break your specs anyway. eslint should flag console.logs if you're using something like the AirBnB style guide or configure it manually. Otherwise you'll want a git pre-commit hook or something.

Comment: A super helpful tip to try to avoid this in the future: modern browsers like chrome have debuggers built into devtools by clicking on the source tab, definitely beats scratching your head and refreshing a lot to see the output of the logs (in chrome at least, you can highlight different expressions in the code as long as it's in the current context and you can see what it evaluates to)

Comment: @DaveNewton, I love the AirBnB style guide, I have had it starred for almost a year now, but never implemented it.

Answer (score 0):

Should probably create two different questions for this (one per language).

For JavaScript, you can short-circuit `console.log` by defining `console.log` to an empty function:

```
console.log = () => {}; // ES6
console.log = function () {}; // ES5
```

The best route though would be to avoid committing with unintentionally `console.log`. The easiest way to do this is to use something like ESLint and ensure you have the rule to flag console calls.

You can take it a step further and define a `pre-push` (or `pre-commit`) trigger for Git (or the equivalent in with other repositories) to fail if your lint doesn't pass.

I'm not super familiar with Ruby, but it likely has equivalents to everything I just mentioned.